# Why is the correlation between a standardized variable and a factor score not 1 when m=1?

Tags: factor-analysis

Assume that there is only one factor (m=1), the model looks like the following: 
$$
Z_i=\mu_i+L_i*F_1+\epsilon_i 
$$
where $i$ is the index of the standardized variables and $L$ is a vector of factor loadings. Correlation between standardized variable $Z_i$ and its only factor score $F_1$ is the corresponding factor loading $L_i$.

$$
Corr(Z_i,F_1)=Cov(Z_i,F_1)=Cov(L_i*F_1,F_1)=L_i
$$

However, I find this counter-intuitive because Z is basically a linear transformation of $F_1$. Shouldn't the correlation be 1?

Comment: $\text{Cov}(Z,F_1)=\text{Cov}(\mu+LF_1+\epsilon,F_1)\neq\text{Cov}(LF_1,F_1)$ ($\epsilon$ cannot just disappear).

Comment: @RichardHardy It is assumed that $ Cov(\epsilon,F_1) = 0 $.

Comment: My bad!........